# Placeholder is not working properly in all browsers

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get placeholder text in firefox and other browsers that don't support the html5 tag option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429520/how-do-i-get-placeholder-text-in-firefox-and-other-browsers-that-dont-support-t)

I have created a login popup box and I used placeholder to show the input field name, but in other browsers like `IE9`, `IE8` and even `IE10` is not showing placeholder text in the input.

How can I resovle this issue? Is there any other way to fill the input field?

```
<input name="username" type="text" value="" placeholder="Username" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3429520/1367163

Answer (score 2):

As OEZI said it's not supported in all browsers.

try this instead

```
<input name="username" type="text" value="" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" />
```

Comment: Default values and placeholders are **not** equivalent.

Comment: as Quentin said this would send the "placeholder"-text as value on form submission wich isn't what html5-placeholder do, so it might not work or need additional checking on submission (if it's a required field for example - with this code, the input isn't empty when the "placeholder" is shown)

Comment: yes I know but it's not that big deal. you can easily handle it.

Answer (score 1):

`placeholder` is part of the new HTML5-features wich isn't fully supported by all browsers till now. for more information, please check:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder (more html5/css3-features: http://caniuse.com/)
- http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/01-placeholder.html (more html5-features: http://wufoo.com/html5/)

**EDIT:**
if you're using jQuery, there's [this little plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) to add support for all browsers down to IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Placeholder is not supported by IE8 till now. You may use

```
<input type="text" name="username" onfocus="if(this.value=='Username') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Username';" />
```

Comment: Default values and placeholders are **not** equivalent.

Comment: as Quentin said this would send the "placeholder"-text as value on form submission wich isn't what html5-placeholder do, so it might not work or need additional checking on submission (if it's a required field for example - with this code, the input isn't empty when the "placeholder" is shown)