# How do I make a HTML input box default text remove AFTER starting to type

Tags: html, input, inputbox

Say I have an input box with default text "name" in it. I would like for the user to click the box, the text stays in the box until the user starts to type.

I am **not** looking for code to clear the input box after focusing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's placeholder attribute

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your name">
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do depends on the version of the browser you are targeting. If the customer uses a browser that support html5 then the answer from @alexndm will work. However if you are targeting a mass audience with number of browser version.

This article here will show how to do it the old way, i.e. using javascript. [How do I get placeholder text in firefox and other browsers that don't support the html5 tag option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429520/how-do-i-get-placeholder-text-in-firefox-and-other-browsers-that-dont-support-t)

Note: the OP of the post I linked also have html5 in case you need it.