# How to display default text for asp.net textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How do I set default text for asp textbox during page load and clear them when focused on..

I know to do it in html textbox using javascript and jquery..But how to do it in asp.net.. Any help please..

I wrote

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Rloginemail" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="25px" 
     BackColor="#ECE8D0" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="#482B1B" 
     Text="E-MAIL" >E-MAIL</asp:TextBox>
```

In the above code you can see `text=email`.. if I use this default text is shown but not cleared on focus..

Comment: Are you referring to having a watermark of sorts?

Comment: What do you mean liquidsnake..

Comment: you want to watermark the textbox , isn't it?

Comment: Or see [How do I get placeholder text in firefox and other browsers that don't support the html5 tag option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429520/how-do-i-get-placeholder-text-in-firefox-and-other-browsers-that-dont-support-t).

Comment: But all these answers puts hint in the left side corner of textbox,but i want in middle..IS that possible..

Comment: Thanks for eveyone ..I did centering..

Comment: I guess that might be done with the watermark css class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HTML 5**

You can use `placeholder` html5 attribute

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" />
```

**jQuery Placeholder Plugin**

If your browser doesnt support then use this [jquery  placeholder](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder)

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned that you can do it for html textbox using javascript or jQuery, but don't know how to do it with Asp.Net textbox. right? Is it just because id of your asp.net textbox changes dynamically and you are not able to access it?. If yes, then you can access the id using following code:

```
document.getElementById("<%=textbox.ClientID%>")
```

You can use above code in the script written in the aspx code to get asp.net textbox and then you can use javascript/jQuery as you know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnFocus` event and set `Text` property to empty string

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Rloginemail" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="25px" BackColor="#ECE8D0" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="#482B1B" Text="E-MAIL" onfocus="if (this.value == 'E-MAIL')  this.value = ''; ">E-MAIL</asp:TextBox>
```

Or, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823983/how-do-i-put-hint-in-a-asptextbox) answer - you can also use asp.net textbox property called `placeholder`:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="Rloginemail" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="25px" 
                     BackColor="#ECE8D0" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="#482B1B" 
                     placeholder="E-MAIL" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: "I know to do it in html textbox using javascript and jquery..But how to do it in asp.net"

Comment: html textbox is not asp textbox. And you cant do it in pure ASP.net as it would require postback to process. Check others solutions if you doubt so

Comment: i know that its not possible purely through ASP.net, nearest would be to use ajax control toolkit, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net you can do it by using ajax control toolkit. we have a TextboxExtender there which can do it besides other things as below

```
<ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TBE" runat="server"
TargetControlID="youTextBoxID"
WatermarkText="YOUR DEFAULT TEXT"
WatermarkCssClass="yourPreferred css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

We use Ajax Control Toolkit's Textbox Watermark extender for this:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-watermark]").each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("data-watermark"));
        $(this).css("color", "#a8a8a8");
        $(this).bind("focus", function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("data-watermark")) $(this).val('');
            $(this).css("color", "#000000");
        });
        $(this).bind("blur", function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val($(this).attr("data-watermark"));
                $(this).css("color", "#a8a8a8");

            }
            else {
                $(this).css("color", "#000000");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

style

```
<style>
.placeholder {
color: #a8a8a8;
```

}

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #a8a8a8;
```

}

```
:-moz-placeholder {
color: #a8a8a8;
```

}

```
.home_textbox{width:155px; height:25px; border:1px solid #c9c5c1; border-radius:5px; position:relative; font-size:13px; color:#b5b0aa; font-family:"Myriad Pro"; padding:0 5px;}
```

textbox

```
<input type="text" name="TxtLogin" id="TxtLogin"
                            class="home_textbox" runat="server" tabindex="1" style="color:Black;" data-watermark="Username" />
```

Comment: You might want to mention where you copied that from and what it does.

Comment: also this is pure html/jquery way to do it - nothing related to asp.net. Funny how it is the right answer for OP

Comment: user didnt tag jquery that doesnt mean he doesnot contain it. and CodeCaster i didnt copy.. I did it in my project .. so please

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433589/input-with-watermark-css-jquery.

Comment: you want proof that i have included in my project and i copy paste it from my project?

Comment: Question was centered differently and accepted answer different