# Fill empty inputs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with PHP+MySQL. In one page I have a form with aprox. 30 inputs.

After showing the form, at the end I execute some jQuery sentences styling the form.

Well, some rows in my SQL have data empty inputs, so I show empty inputs. I want to fill the form with "------" without writing that slashes into DB because makes SQL much bigger.

I'm trying "replaceWith", but i dont know if this implementation with "empty" is correct.
This does not work, even without .is(:empty)

```
<script>
    $('#form').find('input[type=text]').is(':empty').replaceWith(function()
       {
        return this.val('------');
       });
</script>
```

Comment: For one thing you can't `return return`.

Comment: I would suggest doing this server-side instead.   You can simply format the output before returning it with a simple IF without touching the DB, like if(is_null(field)) {field = "----";}

Comment: Missing quotation marks around `:empty`

Comment: @JaredEitnier fixed! Sorry, i had not that written in my file :)

Comment: @DJDavid98 Fixed! That really didn,t know. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<script>
    $('#form').find('input[type=text]').each(function(e){
        if($(this).val()=="") $(this).val("---");
    })       
</script>
```

Comment: That works! as @adeneo write, I need to use .trim to trim off the whitespaces. Thankyou !!!!

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `:empty` finds elements with no children, not elements without a value, and as an input can't have children it finds nothing.

And jQuery's `is()` returns a boolean, not a collection.

jQuery's `replaceWith` replaces the entire element, not just the value.

Check the value instead.

```
$('#form input[type=text]').val(function(_, val) {
    return val.length === 0 ? '------' : val;
});
```

or

```
$('#form input[type=text]').filter(function() {
    return this.value.length === 0;
}).val('------');
```

Throw in a `$.trim` to trim off whitespace if needed

Comment: Wow, thank you. Obviusly I misunderstood the function of empty. Unluckily that two options is not working. I gonna try with $('#form').find('input[type=text]')

Comment: It's not just jQuery's `:empty`, it's the way that CSS selector is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the HTML `placeholder` attribute?

You could use `placeholder` to make the dashes appear in light grey text without actually changing the value of the input. They would automatically be added to any blank fields on your page:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="----" value="asdf" name="notempty"
    title="This has a placeholder, but doesn't show it because the input is filled with something" />
<input type="text" placeholder="----" value="" name="empty"
    title="This is empty, so it shows the dashes" />
```

The placeholder text would not be included in your `$_POST` data. In this example, `$_POST['empty']` would be blank.

The `placeholder` attribute is supported by many of the modern browsers, but not IE9:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

There are various jQuery plugins that imitate this effect as well. You can read about a few of them here:

[How do I get placeholder text in firefox and other browsers that don't support the html5 tag option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429520/how-do-i-get-placeholder-text-in-firefox-and-other-browsers-that-dont-support-t)

Comment: That it is a really good option but I could not use that because after adding the slashes I use other Jquery sentence to convert this inputs to plain text, so if there is no text written in the input, the conversion makes it dissapear