# How to use Angular UI's Bootstrap DatePicker only when the browser does not support date inputs natively?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui

I want to use Angular UI's [Bootstrap DatePicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), but for devices that support the date input type (e.g. `iOS`), I want to use the native Date Picker.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I just [plunked a directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8FnHY?p=preview) that does this by wrapping a `ng-transclude` with a `ng-if`.

**HTML**

```
<div my-if-browser-feature="inputtypes.date">
  <input type="date">
</div>
<div my-if-browser-feature="!inputtypes.date">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    Your browser sucks
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
myApp.directive('myIfBrowserFeature', function() {

  return {
    template: '<div ng-if="hasFeatures"><div ng-transclude></div></div>', 
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      $scope.hasFeatures = true;

      var features = ($attrs.myIfBrowserFeature || "").split(' ');

      var fl = features.length;

      while(fl && $scope.hasFeatures) {
        var f = features[--fl];

        if(f.length === 0) { continue; }

        var cmp = f.charAt(0) === '!' ? false : true;

        if(cmp === false) { f = f.substr(1); }

        var p = Modernizr;
        var q = f.split('.');

        while(q.length && p !== undefined) {
          p = p[q.shift()];
        }

        $scope.hasFeatures = (!p) == (!cmp);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks nifty but overall this can be done using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` too. I don't want to render two elements and show and hide one depending on the browser, I only want to render 1 element and that element itself should not use a custom date picker if the browser already implements the functionality.

Comment: As far as I know this **can't** be done with a `ng-show`/`ng-hide`/`ng-if` directly. For example `ng-if="Modernizr.canvas"` will never render its contents even if the browser supports canvas unless you do something with the scope. But please show me if I'm wrong. 
Besides `ng-show` and `ng-hide` **always** render the elements, `ng-if` on the other hand does not if the expression is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether the browser supports date input using something like Modernizr.  This page has an example http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html

Using this condition, you can display different html components

Comment: I am already using Modernizr in my app, and I know how to detect if a browser supports date/time inputs, but I don't know how to integrate it with Angular.

Comment: There's a question here regarding modernizr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657170/detecting-support-for-specific-html-5-features-via-jquery. Unfortunately angular-bootstrap has a very specific focus in mind. If you're using their element directives, there's no way to programmatically alter the processing of the datepicker directives without overriding the  datepicker-popup attributes directive :(

Comment: A final thought. You could use an `ng-show` for two different divs. One shows the bootstrap picker when the native one isn't available. The other shows the native one. In your controller, assign the scope variable `$scope.nativeDateAvailable = [MODERNIZRCODE];`. Then in the `ng-show`, show the correct elements.